# Add controls dynamically from another class C#

Tags: c#, controls

I have a panel called mainPanel in my Form1 and I want to add controls to it from another class. I tried to set the visibility to public but it didn't work.

This is where I create my controls:

```
public List<Control> addControlsToMain(string SearchWord, Size ContainerSize)
    {
        List<Control> ListOfControls = new List<Control>();

        Panel Box;
        Label Title, Content;

        int PositionCounter = 10;

        foreach (string data in GetSearchData(SearchWord))
        {
            Box = new Panel();
            Title = new Label();
            Content = new Label();

            Box.Size = new Size((int)(ContainerSize.Width * 0.8), 100);
            Title.Size = new Size(Box.Width, 20);
            Content.Size = new Size((int)(Box.Width * 0.8), 60);

            Box.Location = new Point(10, PositionCounter);
            Title.Location = new Point(25, 10);
            Content.Location = new Point(25, 40);

            Title.Text = "Title";
            Content.Text = "Content here";

            ListOfControls.Add(Box);

            Box.Controls.Add(Title);
            Box.Controls.Add(Content);

            PositionCounter += 110;
        }

        return ListOfControls;
    }
```

Where GetSearchData(SearchWord) is just another function that returns random strings in a list, this function addControlsToMain() belongs to my class SearchFunctions.cs (a class separated from the Form1). I've tried to add these controls doing this:

```
            var mainForm = new Form1();
            SearchFunctions src = new SearchFunctions();
            System.Drawing.Size panelSize = mainForm.mainPanel.Size;

            foreach(System.Windows.Forms.Control data in src.addControlsToMain("Stack overflow", panelSize))
            {
                mainForm.mainPanel.Controls.Add(data);
            }
```

My class CommandFunctions.cs is who has to add these controls. How can I add these list of controls to my panel?

Comment: What happens? Have you used the debugger? Do you hit the line where you add it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go about this a few ways. One of which would be to add a `SearchFunctions` object as a a property to your `Form1` class. Then use that object to call the method that adds the controls.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SearchFunctions src = new SearchFunctions(); 

    public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Control> myControls = src.addControlsToMain(mySearchWord, mySize);
        foreach (Control c in myControls)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(c);
            }
    }
}
```

This example uses a button click but you would place that method anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely here:

```
var mainForm = new Form1();
```

You're creating a new instance of Form1 that never gets displayed.

Here are some options:

1. Pass a reference to your **existing** Form1 instance into your class and add the controls using that reference.

or

2. Use the `addControlsToMain()` function directly from the Form itself so you can add the controls using `this` as Juken has demonstrated in his post.

or

3. Pass the controls out to the form using a custom **event**.

Answer (score 0):

### I have rather used webform, but still, this should work: I am basically trying to add controls

- To a ** Panel** (instead of Form)in one class(say Main.cs) And
- Create and add the controls to this Panel from another class(say class1.cs)

========================================================================

Steps:

1.Make use of the appropriate namespaces for calling control class utility
ex: System.Web.UI.Web Controls (in my case)

2.In Main.cs

```
Panel Panel1= new Panel();
 foreach(some condition)
     {
      class1.addControlsToMain("xyz_Searchword", 2, ref Panel1); //Calls the method which creates the controls
     }
```

3. Class1.cs

   ```
     {
       Public static void addControlsToMain(string searchword, int size,ref Panel p1) 
       { 
       List<WebControl> list = new List<WebControl>(); //should be List<Control> for Windows
                   Label lb1, title;

                   lb1 = new Label();
                    title = new Label();

                       lb1.Text = "Test Label Control1";
                       title.Text = "Test Title Label Control";

                      p1.Controls.Add(lb1);
                       p1.Controls.Add(title);
                       list.Add(p1);
                   }
               }
   ```

To cut the long story short, try using Ref keyword. Hope this helps in a bit.

Comment: The `ref` keyword shouldn't be necessary as `Panel` is already a reference type.

Comment: but I had seen my senior using ref keypwords to pass controls like Dropdownlist, etc. I am not sure for Panel though. But assumed it should be the same way for Panel as for dropdownlist. @Juken

Comment: Panel does act the same as DropDownList as they are both reference types but there is little reason to use the `ref` keyword with either. The only reason you would use the `ref` keyword with a reference type would be to change where that reference points to. By default reference types are passed by reference (hence the name) so they can be altered within a method without the `ref` keyword. @svik

Comment: Alright, I will try using it without ref and see , how it goes and whats the difference. Thank you @Juken